# Create dependency graph between classes for .net Project/Solution

Tags: c#, static-analysis

Is there a programmatic way or tool that allows to iterate over all classes in project/assembly and find out other dependent classes?
Resharper has similar functionality, but I wasn't able to find the way to export the results in some easy-to-analyze format.

My end goal is to create dependency graph between classes (per class), not aggregated by project/namespace/etc

My end goal is to get list like that `<Class Name>: <Dependency1>, <Dependency N>`

```
 - Class1: Class2, Class6, Class9   
 - Class2: Class1, Class4
 - Class3: 
 - Class4: Class2, Class5
```

Etc

**Update:**
I am using Visual Studio 2015 Premium.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? The more expensive versions have these tools.

Comment: This is supported in the higher-tier Visual Studio SKUs (Enterprise/Ultimate and maybe Premium): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465141.aspx

Comment: thanks guys, I updated the question with VS version and edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try the tool NDepend that integrates with VS2015 (all SKUs, Premium included) and also VS 2019, 2017, 2013, 2012, 2010 all SKUs except the older *Express* SKU.

With NDepend you can edit in Visual Studio [C# linq queries that are compiled/executed live](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL). For example the code query below shows all classes dependencies:

```
from t in Application.Types
select new { t, t.TypesUsed, t.TypesUsingMe }
```

[image: NDepend Code Query for Dependency]

Code queries results can be exported to graph and this way many kind of dependency graph can be generated: [Call Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call), [Class Inheritance Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Inherit), [Coupling Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Coupling)...

[image: NDepend Generating Graoh fromCode Query]

> I wasn't able to find the way to export the results in some
>   easy-to-analyze format.

In addition to live code querying in Visual Studio, the NDepend code querying is available through an [API](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html) that you can harness to create C# programs and to export any data in any format.

---

The new NDepend version 2020.1 now let's you generate a call graph for a class or a method within a click:

[image: NDepend Dependency Graph to produce a Call Graph]

---

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I was able to get what I wanted with NDepend (by writing the app using C# Api).
NDepend is great, I was blown away by the functionality it provides!

Comment: We're glad NDepend is helping you to achieve what you want :)

Comment: Good tool but you forgot to mention that it costs

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is Code Maps. I'm not sure if they're available in VS 2015 Premium now, but they weren't upon initial release. The comments on this article might help you out: [New ways to quickly create a Code Map](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/12/new-ways-to-quickly-create-a-code-map/).

Comment: thank you. by default it shows dependencies aggregated by project/namespace. Is there a way to display class-level dependencies?